# Sending Data From iOS App to PHP Script

Tags: php, ios, iphone, objective-c

I feel like this shouldn't be this complicated but here I am after spending the last 2 days trying to get this to work. I'm trying to send two variables from my iOS app to a php script I have on a server. The database adds an entry but the 2 information fields are blank. I'm alright with Objective C but new to PHP.

PHP Code

```
<?php
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
                    mysql_connect("Server","Username","Password");
                    mysql_select_db("comments");
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, name, comment) VALUES ('','$name','$comment')");
?>
```

Objective C Code

```
NSString *name = @"Name1";
    NSString *comment = @"Comment1";
    NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&name=%@&comment=%@",name,comment];
    NSData *myRequestData =[myRequestString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[myRequestData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.notguiltyapp.com/harris.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    // Set Request Body
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work. Why did you add quotes to each variable?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I fixed the problem after many more hours. I took out

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and replaced it with

```
NSData *returnData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
```